# basic info about C# classes and inheriting from other classes

Tags: class, c#-4.0

I'd like to write a class which extends the functionality of the MembershipProvider and MembershipUser. But my knowledge in this area is woefully lacking.

My cs file looks something like this:

```
namespace Mech
{
    public class Mechs : MembershipProvider
    {
        private static Database dbConn = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("main");

        public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

At this point it's complaining about all the abstract members not being implemented. I don't really need to change every single member of membershipProvider, just a handful. So what would be the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you are inheriting from an abstract class you need to implement all the non-abstract methods and proporties.

You don't necessarily have to change everythingthing . You can just leave them as it after implementation.

> You can use VS smart features to save you from lots of typing and the parent class has lots and lots of abstract members and methods.

Click on MembershipProvide , Wait for Intellisences to show you the hint as in below picture:
(Alternatively press **Alt+Shift+F10**)
[image]

Now that's it , you will have your class implementing all the abstract methods and proporties.

[image]

So what will happen when you will try to access Field1:

```
StackOverflow stackOverFlow = new StackOverflow();
            String myString = stackOverFlow.Field1;
```

[image]

Comment: So what does throwing NotImplementedException do? I'm guessing it literally just throws an error saying it was not implemented. So in this case I just don't call those methods through my class and instead call them through the standard membership provider, correct?

Comment: you can not call them through MembershipProvider as it's an abstract class and you can not create an instance of it. 

Instead what it will do is , when you want to access Field1 through Stackoverflow (Mechs object in your example) object it will throw an not implemented error   . It should not be a problem for you as you said you are not using the propories

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this article at codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_security/article.php/c19415/Writing-a-Custom-Membership-Provider-for-the-Login-Control-in-ASPNET-20.htm).  You only need to implement what you're going to use, and you can leave the rest throwing NotImplementedExceptions.  Additionally, you can extend an existing provider (e.g. `SqlMembershipProvider`) and override `ValidateUser` or anything else your heart desires.

Comment: Implementing an abstract class that doesn't implement everything violates the Liskov Substitution principle.  Something that implements an interface should be able to be substituted for any other type that implements that same interface.  If an implementation throws a bunch of `NotImplementedException`s it can't really be used as that type everywhere...

Comment: Thankfully, not everything needs to follow the "rules" (LSP is more of a guideline/definition than anything else).  Specialized requirements don't always require 100% implementation.